# Casting between subclass/interface and superclass

Tags: java, class, interface, casting

Consider the following code:

```
interface IFace {}

abstract class Supertype {}

class Subtype1 extends Supertype implements IFace {}
class Subtype2 extends Supertype implements IFace {}
class Subtype3 extends Supertype {}

class Foo {
    //Contains elements of Subtype1 and Subtype2
    List<IFace>     ifaceList = new ArrayList<IFace>();

    //Contains elements of Subtype1, Subtype2, and Subtype3
    List<Supertype> superList = new ArrayList<Supertype>();   

    void CopyItem() {
        superList.add( (Supertype) ifaceList.someElement() );
    }
}
```

Is it safe to cast an `IFace` element to `Supertype` if I know that only Subtypes will implement `IFace`? Is it even possible to ensure that only Subtypes will implement `IFace`?

I'm trying to use `IFace` as a marker interface to keep only certain Subtypes in the first list and allow any Subtypes in the second list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to cast an IFace element to Supertype if I know that only Subtypes will implement IFace?

Yes.

> Is it even possible to ensure that?

If you mean "is it possible to ensure that only subclasses of `Supertype` implement `IFace`" - no. An interface can be implemented by anything.

If you mean "is it possible to ensure that the cast will succeed" - yes, you can use `instanceof` before casting.

Comment: instanceof? ..... (I understand your point about but you get mine too I suppose).

Comment: @assylias: Not sure what you mean here. You can ensure that the cast is safe, but that's not what the OP was looking to ensure, as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's what I meant yes. Not sure if it is / isn't the question.

Comment: Consider `IFace` a marker interface to ensure that only certain Subtypes are in the first list, but any Subtype can be in the second. Is there a better way?

Comment: @BrianTempleton: Ah, I see - while all implementations of `IFace` are `Supertype` subclasses, not all subclasses implement `IFace`. I've removed the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way would be having Supertype implement IFace. If that's not possible, then it's safe to cast an IFace element to Supertype as long as **every class** that implement IFace is also a Supertype subclass. You'll have to assure that holds true for the time being, which is rather error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to cast an IFace element to Supertype if I know that only Subtypes will implement IFace?

If you know for sure that all IFace elements also extends Supertype then it won't be a problem. But in the future this may not be true anymore.

> Is it even possible to ensure that?

Yes. You can try catch on the ClassCastException or even better test it before cast with operator `instanceof`

```
void CopyItem() {
    IFace obj = ifaceList.someElement();
    if (obj instanceof Supertype) superList.add( (Supertype)obj );
    else System.err.println("WARNING: IFace object is not a Supertype.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to cast an IFace element to Supertype if I know that only
>   Subtypes will implement IFace?

If you know your code, and every class that implements `IFace` is also a subclass of `Supertype`, there is no problem, but you can always check for `Supertype` using the `instanceof` operator, to be sure.

> Is it even possible to ensure that?

Consider the following modification to your code:

```
interface IFace {}

abstract class Supertype {}

abstract class SupertypeAndFace extends Supertype implements IFace {}

class Subtype1 extends SupertypeAndFace {}
class Subtype2 extends SupertypeAndFace {}
class Subtype3 extends Supertype {}

class Foo {
    //Contains elements of Subtype1 and Subtype2
    List<SupertypeAndFace> ifaceList = new ArrayList<SupertypeAndFace>();

    //Contains elements of Subtype1, Subtype2, and Subtype3
    List<Supertype>        superList = new ArrayList<Supertype>();   

    void CopyItem() {
        superList.add(ifaceList.someElement());
    }
}
```

There, the cast is not neccesary, as you ensure that every instance of `SupertypeAndFace` extends `Supertype` and implements `IFace`.

After all, if `Supertype` and `IFace` are so related that you know that all (or at least most) of the clases that implements `IFace` also are subclasses of `Supertype`, maybe you need that new abstraction.

But, if you also want `ifaceList` to contain other elements that implements `IFace`, but are not subtypes of `Supertype`, this solution is not valid. If that is the case, you can use the `instanceof` operator to check for the safety of the cast, as explained by other answers.

```
void CopyItem() {
    if (ifaceList.someElement() instanceof Supertype) {
        superList.add( (Supertype) ifaceList.someElement() );
    } else {
        // Throw exception if necessary
    }
}
```